# MVC 5 - Error page not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-error-pages

I want to trap 404 page not founds to go to a nice little sexy page I've created.
Let's start at **step 1** first.

**1)**---------

I have an `Error.chstml` in my Shared views folder.

**2)**---------

I have added:

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

to my Web.Config (in the root directory) inside `system.web`

**3)----------**

I have added:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

to my Global.asax ApplicationStart method and added a FilterConfig.cs file to my App Start folder with the following code:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

**4)------------**

I then tried to add this to the customErrors XML:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error" />
```

**5)--------------**

I had tried to create my own ErrorController and used my routes to redirect to it... but they never get fired:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "404-PageNotFound",
            "{*url}",
             new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }
        );

...

public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ViewResult Error404()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This still returns the ugly smelly web 1.0 error page :) : `HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.`

---

**What am I doing wrong???? Something that I thought would take like 20 seconds has ended up taking 2 hours lol**

Comment: From your question, you don't have "NotFound" action in the ErrorController class. `new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }` is then wrong. What error are you getting?

Comment: Bleurgh, sorry forgot to change that was piecing this question up over a period of time :) ignore that typo. thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current routes it will fail to redirect to that `Error404` action method. Start by removing the `404-PageNotFound` route. Then rename `Error404` method to `Index`. Don't forget to rename the view too.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now when user is redirected to http://example.org/Error like you specified web.config, this action method will be called.

Comment: touché - Thanks matey. I also just found out that I can do a switch on context.Response.StatusCode so that's cool too! nice